# Create DNA Sequences of length n

Tags: python, permutation

How can we use recursion to calculate all dna sequences of length n in a function.

For instance if the function is given 2, it returns ['AA', 'AC', 'AT', 'AG', 'CA', 'CC', 'CT', 'CG', 'TA', 'TC', 'TT', 'TG', 'GA', 'GC', 'GT', 'GG']

etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
def all_seq(n, curr, e, ways):
    """All possible sequences of size n given elements e.

    ARGS
        n: size of sequence
        curr: a list used for constructing sequences
        e: the list of possible elements (could have been a global list instead)
        ways: the final list of sequences
    """
    if len(curr) == n:
        ways.append(''.join(curr))
        return

    for element in e:
        all_seq(n, list(curr) + [element], e, ways)


perms = []
all_seq(2, [], ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G'], perms)
print(perms)
```

The ouput:

```
['AA', 'AC', 'AT', 'AG', 'CA', 'CC', 'CT', 'CG', 'TA', 'TC', 'TT', 'TG', 'GA', 'GC', 'GT', 'GG']
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with just input n?

Comment: Yes, you can. `ways` and `e` can be made into global (or defined outside the function but within the func body's scope). What you have left to get rid of is `curr` which can also be a list of lists (think of memoization) defined in the same location `ways` and `e` are defined.

Answer (score 2):

[`functools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) will give all combinations of a given iterable, the second argument `r` is the length of the combinations returned

```
itertools.permutations('ACGT', length)
```

Comment: Thanks! How can we use recursion though?

Comment: *you* don't need to use recursion.  *this* function will do what is needed plenty fast.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want `itertools.product('ACGT', repeat=n)`.  Note that this will grow enormously fast (`4^n` elements of `n` length).

If your assignment is to do it recursively, consider how you would get all n+1-length options that start with a n-length prefix.  The naive recursive option might be rather slow compared to itertools, if you need to use it in anger.